# How to create an image using ffmpeg and PHP? 

Tags: php, image, video, ffmpeg

I'm using [this script](http://blog.amnuts.com/2007/06/22/create-a-random-thumbnail-of-a-video-file/), but I'm not able to create the image.

My file is [here](http://sahu.vipin.googlepages.com/thumb.php).

Comment: That file you provide is virtually useless as it is intrinsically linked to your particular PHP installation.  How about telling us what kind of errors or results you're seeing instead?

Comment: no image is genrated through this script

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not working because you never execute the `$cmd`. To actually execute the `$cmd` you either need to use `popen()`, `proc_open()`, or `exec()`.

Try this function. It should generate an image as long as ffmpeg is accessible. To make it accessible add it to `$path` in linux, drop it into the `windows/system32` folder in Windows. Or add it to the environmental variables in the control panel in Windows.

```
/**
 * ExtractThumb, extracts a thumbnail from a video
 *
 * This function loads a video and extracts an image from a frame 4 
 * seconds into the clip
 * @param $in string the input path to the video being processed
 * @param $out string the path where the output image is saved
 */
function ExtractThumb($in, $out)
{
    $thumb_stdout;
    $errors;
    $retval = 0;

    // Delete the file if it already exists
    if (file_exists($out)) { unlink($out); }

    // Use ffmpeg to generate a thumbnail from the movie
    $cmd = "ffmpeg -itsoffset -4 -i $in -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 $out 2>&1";
    exec($cmd, $thumb_stdout, $retval);

    // Queue up the error for processing
    if ($retval != 0) { $errors[] = "FFMPEG thumbnail generation failed"; }

    if (!empty($thumb_stdout))
    {
        foreach ($thumb_stdout as $line)
        {
            echo $line . "
\n";
        }
    }

    if (!empty($errors))
    {
        foreach ($errors as $error)
        {
            echo $error . "
\n";
        }
    }
}
```

`$thumb_stdout` - displays the output the same as it would in the CLI. This is useful to see the details of what ffmpeg is doing, and to see where it crashes if it isn't working.

`$errors` - Will display an error if the CLI exits with an error code (IE, if ffmpeg crashes).

Comment: could also use `system()`, among few other options

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP program basically calls `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` twice. Try that on the command line first!  You can

```
echo "<pre>$cmd</pre>"
```

to find out what exactly your PHP script is doing, and then try that exact command on the command line.

The first command should look something like

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/beta/clock.avi 2>&1
```

This is where you place the `echo`s:

```
// get the duration and a random place within that
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video 2>&1";
echo "<pre>$cmd</pre>"

if (preg_match('/Duration: ((\d+):(\d+):(\d+))/s', `$cmd`, $time)) {
    $total = ($time[2] * 3600) + ($time[3] * 60) + $time[4];
    $second = rand(1, ($total - 1));
}

// get the screenshot
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video -an -ss $second -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $image 2>&1";
echo "<pre>$cmd</pre>"
$return = `$cmd`;
```

Answer (score 1):

First install ffmpeg-php (http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/)

And then you can use of this simple code:

```
<?php
$frame = 10;
$movie = 'test.mp4';
$thumbnail = 'thumbnail.png';

$mov = new ffmpeg_movie($movie);
$frame = $mov->getFrame($frame);
if ($frame) {
    $gd_image = $frame->toGDImage();
    if ($gd_image) {
        imagepng($gd_image, $thumbnail);
        imagedestroy($gd_image);
        echo '<img src="'.$thumbnail.'">';
    }
}
?>
```